# Validation Issue - The tag:"script" is not allowed within: "option"

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm fairly new to using code. Is there a way I can validate this code within an option? Should I be using CData?

```
<option value='4 EUR 36' selected="selected">4 EUR 36 - <script language="JavaScript" src="http://remote.cart.com/data.asp?storeid=12345&amp;rddcode=17001420&amp;type=2" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thks in advance

Comment: why are you using a script tag inside an option?

Comment: ¿Why would you need to place a script there? It can be anywhere and still modify your select, option and other tags in the document.

Comment: Thks @Alfabravo, what would be a better idea which would still show the same javascript data when the option is selected from the dropdown?

Comment: Well... we don't know what do you want to do. I doubt http://remote.cart.com/data.asp is a javascript file. Show us your javascript code and tell us what you need it to do

Comment: @user1208813: JavaScript runs as soon as it's added to the DOM, so just adding a `<script>` to an `<option>` won't make it run when it's selected.

Comment: @Alfabrvo Thks for your comments. Not sure if my problem is clear? At the moment the code above works great. When the user selects an option the sizing data shows 4 EUR 36 - and also the Javascript adds either an "In Stock" or "Out of Stock" message from the stock status in my the 3rd party cart system. All I'm concerned about is this will not get WC3 markup validation. I would rather use correct/different code hence my query? Is it possible to do the same job but using correct code?

Comment: @user1208813: Can you post the JavaScript code that is being ran?

Comment: Just after the body tag :- '<script language="JavaScript" src="http://remote.cart.com/data.asp?storeid=12345&amp;categoryid=3" type="text/javascript"></script>'

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't have a script in the middle of an option element.

I can't think of any reason to put there that doesn't involve it outputting content using `document.write`. Change it so that it performs [DOM manipulation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML) instead and make sure it doesn't run until the select element exists (either by putting it after the element or using a load or ready event handler).

Comment: Or even better, place it in the head or end of the body.

Comment: Thks for your comments. As I'm no expert some further explanation would help me based on your comments. Each selected option has stock related data for that option which the script is loading from a 3rd party source. How else would this be loaded for the user to see on selection?

Comment: @user1208813: You'd have to load the JavaScript file (from inside JavaScript) when the option was selected.

Comment: @user1208813: On second thought, that may not be the best idea.